# My code with remarks in Traditional Chinese characters is taken as spam

Tags: support, spam, unicode

If I embed the following code with Chinese characters as remarks, the post is taken as spam, I need to remove all the Chinese characters to pass it. Please elaborate on this and advise, thanks.

```
# 2024-02-04 WeightSet
#            投資組合為1將權重k等分分配到n個股票，每個股票可分配權重0(零),1/k,2/k,...1(全部)
#            將k等分分配到n個股票，即「從n中取k可重複的組合」，組合數為 C(n+k-1,n-1)
#            故權重編號範圍為1~C(n+k-1,n-1)
#            權重串列(整數版)為(n,0,...0,0),(n-1,1,...,0,0),...(0,0,...,0,n)
#            由左向右移動，直到無法移動為主
#            權重串列(小數版) = 權重串列(整數版)/n
#            本類別是將權重編號對應到權重組合串列：亦將權重串列反向對應回權重編號
class WeightSet:
    def __init__(self, k, n):
        self._k = k
        self._n = n
        next_weight_list = [0]*n
        next_weight_list[0] = k
        # 整數版權重串列
        all_weight_tuples = {}
        # 權重串列總數(初始值1)
        weight_tuple_cnt = 1
        
        # 遍歷所有的權重串列並存在 all_weight_lists 先以整數權重計算
        while True:
            all_weight_tuples[weight_tuple_cnt] = tuple(next_weight_list)
            next_found = False    
        
            # 以下皆從左邊開始
            # 找出第一個非零的位置
            first_nonzero_pos = next((pos_i for pos_i, value_i in enumerate(next_weight_list) \
                                      if value_i>0), None)
        
            # 如果可以的話向右搬一個權重
            if first_nonzero_pos < n-1:
                next_weight_list[first_nonzero_pos+1] += 1 # 右一股票權重加1
                next_weight_list[first_nonzero_pos] -= 1 # 本股票權重減1
                rem_weight = next_weight_list[first_nonzero_pos] # 減1後剩下權重值
                if first_nonzero_pos>0 and rem_weight >0:
                    # 剩下權重值全部移到最左邊
                    next_weight_list[0] = rem_weight
                    next_weight_list[first_nonzero_pos] = 0
        
                weight_tuple_cnt += 1
                next_found = True
            
            if not next_found: break

        # 儲存 weight_tuple_cnt
        self._weight_tuple_cnt = weight_tuple_cnt

        # 整數權重轉成小數權重(除以k)
        all_weight_tuples.update((x, tuple(z/k for z in y)) for x, y in all_weight_tuples.items())
        
        # 儲存 
        all_weight_tuples_bidict = bidict(all_weight_tuples)
        self._weight_tuple_from_id = all_weight_tuples_bidict
        self._weight_id_from_tuple = all_weight_tuples_bidict.inverse

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self._n

    @property
    def k(self):
        return self._k

    @property
    def weight_tuple_cnt(self):
        return self._weight_tuple_cnt
    
    @property
    def weight_tuple_from_id(self):
        return self._weight_tuple_from_id

    @property
    def weight_id_from_tuple(self):
        return self._weight_id_from_tuple
```

Comment: If the comments are relevant to understand the code, translate to English (or the appropriate language for the site you want to post this). Otherwise remove them as we only need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322508/not-allowed-to-post-because-body-cannot-contain-text/322510#322510